# Bot Framework Twilio With Multiple Numbers

Tags: twilio, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot that I've built that's running on the Azure Bot Service with a Twilio Channel.  I'm sending Proactive activities via my Twilio channel.  Everything is working fine.  I just got a request that a customer wants to have their own phone number.  I would like to just have 1 bot service running but have multiple Twilio phone numbers go into this.

My thought was that I could setup an API service which would then be the incoming message call back / webhook from Twilio which then would use the Directline API to the Bot Framework.  It would essentially just replace the https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms service.  The problem is that I'm not sure I could still have the proactive messages working - it seems like the Directline 3.0 API works only when a conversation is started first with it.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this if this would work or have any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the approach which you mentioned above would be ideal. Each Web App Bot/Bot Channels Registration can only be associated with one Twilio number. I will elaborate on the steps which you mentioned above:

- Create a server running the Twilio SMS API code which forwards the messages to the bot via the DirectLine API. The user sends a message to this server.
- For every activity sent to the bot, make sure to include the number: Activity.ChannelData = new { fromNumber: <123-456-7890> }. The Server forwards the message to the bot.
- You will need to re-attach the fromNumber to the bot's outgoing activity so that your Twilio API server knows where to send the outgoing message to. The Bot sends the reply to the server.
- The Twilio API server sends Activity.Text to the user. The Server forwards message from bot to user.

For the [proactive messages](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3653#issuecomment-338767085) part, you can add a conversation property to the address param, and set the id to the user's phone number.

Example:

```
bot.beginDialog(
  {
    user: { id: '+1234567890' },
    bot: { id: '+9876543210' },
    conversation: { id: '+1234567890' },
    channelId: 'sms',
    serviceUrl: 'https://sms.botframework.com'
  },
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thank you so much - this helps a lot. 

On the Twilio SMS Channel - it looks like it's creating a conversation for each phone number.  The conversation Id is like "sms*2fconversations*2f+1PHONE#HERE".  For my Multi Number Twilio  client when I connect via the Direct Line API it creates a unique conversation.   Is that Ok if I use 1 conversation for multiple incoming and outgoing messages?  Will the state accessors work correctly for each phone number?  Or should I startup 1 conversation per phone number?   Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest having 1 conversation per phone number. Also, if you found the answer helpful, can you please accept and upvote it so that it helps others? Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I think I have another question but I'll post that as a new topic.  Thanks again.

Comment: I may have many conversations (like 1000+). If I create 1 conversation per client - what is the best way to receive messages for all these conversations?  If I use the Direct Line Post / Get method I would have to iterate through 1000+ conversations checking for new messages 1 time per second.  If I use WebSockets then I'm going to have to create a connection for each conversation.  (probably overloading the system resources).  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ryan did you get an answer to your latest question regarding the need to cycle through many conversations? Did you find a better/different approach to solve the multiple twilio problem?

Comment: @Gotts - yes we got this working but it's sort of tricky as you have to build out a large amount of infrastructure.  Now that the A2P changes went into effect for Twilio, I'd imagine a lot of other people will need to do this same thing in the future as well.  Hopefully they will build this into the Twlio channel.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that. Would love to hear more of what you had to do. Any diagrams you can share? Also did you consider just using the twilio framework for your chatbot as opposed to Azure, to simplify this issue?